# How to merge a list of multiple dictionaries into a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following list of dictionaries in Python3.x:

```
list_of_dictionaries = [{0:3523, 1:3524, 2:3540, 4:3541, 5:3542}, 
                        {0:7245, 1:7246, 2:7247, 3:7248, 5:7249, 6:7250},
                        {1:20898, 2:20899, 3:20900, 4:20901, 5:20902}]
```

In this case, it's a single list with three dictionaries.

I would like to efficiently merge this into a single dictionary with lists as values; here is the correct answer:

```
correct = {0:[3523, 7245], 1:[3524, 7246, 20898], 2:[3540, 7247, 20899], 
               3:[7248, 20900], 4:[3541, 20901], 5:[3542, 7249, 20902], 6:[7250]}
```

My first thought was a list comprehension like this:

```
dict(pair for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries for pair in dictionary.items())
```

But this is wrong, as it doesn't include lists of values:

```
{0: 7245, 1: 20898, 2: 20899, 4: 20901, 5: 20902, 3: 20900, 6: 7250}
```

I'm also worried about how to efficiently as possible create value lists. It may not scale to large lists/large dictionaries either.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `defaultdict`

You can use `collections.defaultdict`. Your dictionary comprehension will never work as you are not defining any lists. This is likely to be more efficient than using a dictionary comprehension, which would involve iterating each dictionary for each unique key.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

for d in list_of_dictionaries:
    for k, v in d.items():
        dd[k].append(v)
```

Result:

```
print(dd)

defaultdict(list,
            {0: [3523, 7245],
             1: [3524, 7246, 20898],
             2: [3540, 7247, 20899],
             4: [3541, 20901],
             5: [3542, 7249, 20902],
             3: [7248, 20900],
             6: [7250]})
```

#### Dictionary comprehension

A dictionary comprehension is *possible* but this requires calculating the union of keys and iterating the list of dictionaries for each of these keys:

```
allkeys = set().union(*list_of_dictionaries)

res = {k: [d[k] for d in list_of_dictionaries if k in d] for k in allkeys}

{0: [3523, 7245],
 1: [3524, 7246, 20898],
 2: [3540, 7247, 20899],
 3: [7248, 20900],
 4: [3541, 20901],
 5: [3542, 7249, 20902],
 6: [7250]}
```

#### Time complexity

Consider these terms:

```
n = sum(map(len, list_of_dictionaries))
m = len(set().union(*list_of_dictionaries))
k = len(list_of_dictionaries)
```

In this context, the `defaultdict` solution will have complexity O(*n*), while the dictionary comprehension will have complexity O(*mk*), where *mk* >= *n*.

Answer (score 4):

why not just use `for` loops? for example:

```
final = {}

for i in list_of_dictionaries:
    for k in i:
        if not k in final:
            final[k] = []
        final[k].append(i[k])


print(final)
```

**Outputs final as:**

`{0: [3523, 7245], 1: [3524, 7246, 20898], 2: [3540, 7247, 20899], 4: [3541, 20901], 5: [3542, 7249, 20902], 3: [7248, 20900], 6: [7250]}`

Comment: Simplicity FTW!

Answer (score 0):

Using *groupby* and *itemgetter* we could first create a flat list of tuples that represent the `keys and values` of each subdict.  Then we can use *groupby* on our sorted new list. From there we can create our new dictionary using `k` and the items in `index[1]` of `list(g)`

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

d = {}
new_lod = sorted([(j, i[j]) for i in lod for j in i], key=itemgetter(0))
for k, g in groupby(new_lod, key=itemgetter(0)):
    d[k] = [i[1] for i in list(g)]

# {0: [3523, 7245], 1: [3524, 7246, 20898], 2: [3540, 7247, 20899], 3: [7248, 20900], 4: [3541, 20901], 5: [3542, 7249, 20902], 6: [7250]}
```

Comment: The list around g is not necessary as it's an iterable and you are creating a ist anyway (like in the other answers using groupby). Personally I find the use of i and j hard to read as they are usually used for numbers.

Answer (score -1):

You first need to flatten the dictionaries:

```
flattened_pairs = (
    pair for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries for pair in dictionary.items()
)
```

Then you can use `itertools.groupby` to group the values. It expects the values to be sorted by key.

```
key_fn = lambda pair: pair[0]

merged = {
    k: [pair[1] for pair in g]
    for k, g in groupby(
        sorted(flattened_pairs, key=key_fn),
        key=key_fn
    )
}

print(merged)
```

Output:

> {0: [3523, 7245], 1: [3524, 7246, 20898], 2: [3540, 7247, 20899], 3:
>   [7248, 20900], 4: [3541, 20901], 5: [3542, 7249, 20902], 6: [7250]}

Comment: How is this different from my answer below?

Comment: @Ajax1234 your answer only appeared after I finished typing. I submitted it anyway in case it helps someone better to understand the problem.